# Meaning of держава in the Russian Anthem

Tags: значения

What is the meaning of держава in the first sentence of the Russian anthem, is it state or power? [Wiktionary lists](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0) both words!

Comment: Aren't 'state' and 'power' synonyms?

Comment: They are not really synonyms to me. As you can see, this are two different words in English.

Comment: @Mohamed Ahmed AFAIK they are in fact synonyms in English. A "power" means "strong state".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Россия — священная наша держава,
>   Россия — любимая наша страна.
>   Могучая воля, великая слава —
>   Твоё достоянье на все времена!

Here the word **держава** is synonym of state. Usually this is the main meaning of the word. You'll rarely hear it in everyday speech however.

The second meaning is "the power": "Конечно, царь, сильна твоя держава." However this meaning is used mostly in poetic texts and is even rarer that the first meaning.

In old times one of the attributes of the Tsar was called "держава" as well - it looked like a golden sphere with a cross atop of it.

Here is an article from Ushakov's dictionary:

> ДЕРЖА́ВА, державы, жен.
>   1. Независимое государство, имеющее влияние в международных делах (полит. офиц.). Великие державы. Малые державы.
>   2. Государственная власть, владычество (поэт.). «Конечно, царь, сильна твоя держава.» Пушкин.
>   3. Золотой шар с крестом наверху, служивший эмблемой власти монарха (ист.).
>   4. Приспособление для держания чего-нибудь, напр. металла при обработке (спец.).

As for 4th example - I have never heard or read the word держава in this meaning, so I think it is very special term.

Держава as power:

> Что есть всему держава? Бог, Николушка, всему держава. А бог есть любовь, ― возвещает сладчайший апостол. [А. И. Эртель. Гарденины, их дворня, приверженцы и враги (1889)]
>
> Она вспомнила ту, отчасти искреннюю, хотя и много преувеличенную, роль матери, живущей для сына, которую она взяла на себя в последние годы, и с радостью почувствовала, что в том состоянии, в котором она находилась, у ней есть держава, независимая от положения, в которое она станет к мужу и к Вронскому. Эта держава ― был сын. В какое бы положение она ни стала, она не может покинуть сына. [Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина (1878)]
>
> И тако сии вышеозначенные древние российские провинции и городы, притом и сия Ижерская Земля, была под владением от времен державы Царя Феодора Ивановича, от 1594-го и 1609-го годов по 1703-й год, более ста лет, под владением шведским будучи находились. 8. Настает держава Петра Великаго. [А. И. Богданов. Описание Санктпетербурга (1751)]
>
> По долгом рассуждении о формах правления, коими управляются общества, как то: о демократическом [народодержавие], аристократическом [благородных держава], олигархическом [немногих нарочитых начальствование], монархическом [единоначалие царское], и о разных обязательствах и должностях гражданских, чего всего, коль ни важного, краткость предложить попускает, притом также и о так называемых смешанных державах, (...) [В.К. Тредиаковский. Слово о мудрости, благоразумии и добродетели (1752)]

Comment: «Конечно, царь, сильна твоя держава.» - definitely this bit means the state, not власть.

Comment: @Anixx This is an example from Ushakov's dictionary for the meaning of держава as власть. In this verse Шуйский ensures the Tsar that самозванец doesn't have enough power to owerthrow him.

Comment: in this case I suspect he refers figuratively to the orb (like saying "of course, your sword is strong" meaning the army or refering similarly the sceptre).

Comment: "Your sword is strong, your crown is shining, your orb is powerful, your sceptre is far-reaching" etc as a poetic device

Comment: Well, seems you are right, but this usage is definitely archaic.

Answer (score 3):

The English word "power" has different meanings.

In "state power" it means the ability to control, might, force.

In "great power", "regianal power", "superpower" and international treaties it means a strong state.

Russian word *держава* means a strong state. I never encountered it in the meaning "state control/might", I think no such meaning exists in modern Russian.

The other meaning of держава is state regalia in form of an orb with a cros on top.

Answer (score 3):

*Держава* is a CS loanword (*дръжава* in OCS) which is a calque from Greek *κράτος* ("power, rule, authority"). You can find the root of this word in English "democracy" and "bureaucracy".

The Greek word in turn derives from *κρατέω* ("I hold"), so the Slavonic word *дръжати* ("to hold") was used to form the calque.

This word in Russian is of grand style (*высокий штиль*) and as such better corresponds to "power" rather than "state", like in *сверхдержава* ("superpower"), *региональная держава* ("regional power") etc. Thus said, "power" would be the correct word to translate this word in the anthem.

Answer (score 2):

It means "a strong and powerful state". Predominantly used in pompous texts and rhetoric.